# Question on uniquely $p$-divisible groups

Tags: group-theory, modules

I know that an abelian group is uniquely (i.e. torsion-free) divisible iff is has a natural structure of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Is it true that an abelian group is uniquely $p$-divisible iff it has a natural structure of a $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$-module?

Comment: It's a simple exercise. What have you tried? The question is not suitable for this site anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For an idea, cribbed from Vipul Naik at [Characteristic subgroup of uniquely p-divisible group that is not uniquely p-divisible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56128/characteristic-subgroup-of-uniquely-p-divisible-group-that-is-not-uniquely-p-div): if your abelian group is uniquely $p$-divisible, then multiplication by $p$ is a group automorphism, which means division by $p$ is also a group automorphism.